# Trouble with custom authorization attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization

**AuthorizeAttribute**

```
public class PSAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return false;
    }        
}
```

**TestClass**

```
[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    [TestMethod]        
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(TestMore());
    }

    [PSAuthorize]
    public string TestMore()
    {
        return "Test Success";
    }
}
```

**App.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Defaultconnection" connectionString="Private"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>

    <membership defaultProvider="CMSP">
        <providers>

            <add name="CMSP"
                 type="PS.Authentication.CustomMembershipProvider"
                 connectionStringName ="Defaultconnection"/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Problem**

I've been working on this for several hours now...

So far I have not managed to get the `AuthorizeCore` to trigger and I have no idea what is wrong.

I've attempted to create a new MVC (v3) project and add the same code there and it works.. but in our project it suddenly does not...

Am I missing something..?

I'm attempting to make this work in combination with a custom membership provider but I have no idea yet how to... first I need this attribute to trigger a halt when a person is not authorized.

CustomMembershipProvider is a override on Membership with only `throw new NotImplementedException()' in all properties / methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the Authorize attribute to decorate a controller ar an action method.

Why? Because the attribute requires a http context that is recieved on every request.
Test methods cannot provide this context, further more, the attribute is not even used for cases where no HttpContext is provided.

try tesing on a action method to see if that will do the trick

```
[PSAuthorize]
public ActionResult Home()
{
    return View();
}
```

If this will work, find a way to insert an http context in your test project.

Comment: So It is not possible to use this attribute for a webservice to check whether the logged in person has access to the method or not?

Comment: I am not sure you can use it in WCF, but i am sure you can use it in MVC and WebApi, but only for Action methods and controllers. If your web service relies on the new WebApi that follows the same MVC pattern then yes you can use it. If a classic WCF with data contracts is used, do some documentation, as i don't think you can use the same attribute (a different method exists).

Comment: Different method would probably be PrincipalPermission I think... Thanks!